# Is there a way I can Query Missing numbers in a table?

Tags: sql, algorithm, db2

I work for a Logistics Company and we have to have a 7 digit Pro Number on each piece of freight that is in a pre-determined order. So we know there is gaps in the numbers, but is there any way I can Query the system and find out what ones are missing?

So show me all the numbers from 1000000 to 2000000 that do not exist in column name trace_number.

So as you can see below the sequence goes 1024397, 1024398, then 1051152 so I know there is a substantial gap of 26k pro numbers, but is there anyway to just query the gaps?

[image]

```
Select t.trace_number, 
integer(trace_number) as number,
ISNUMERIC(trace_number) as check

from trace as t
left join tlorder as tl on t.detail_number = tl.detail_line_id


where left(t.trace_number,1) in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
and date(pick_up_by) >= current_date - 1 years
and length(t.trace_number) = 7
and t.trace_type = '2'
and site_id in ('SITE5','SITE9','SITE10')
and ISNUMERIC(trace_number) = 'True'


order by 2
fetch first 10000 rows only
```

Comment: Not a pretty answer so I'll leave it as a comment...create a temporary table and populate it with every number from 1000000 to 2000000 (use a simple loop to populate).  Take this temp table and left join to trace, where trace.tracenumber is null will bring back all 'unused' numbers.

Comment: In PostgreSQL I think you could use `SELECT t.trace_number + 1 FROM trace t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trace AS t2 WHERE t2.trace_number = t.trace_number + 1)` to get the starting point of each gap range; presumably DB2 allows something similar.  A similar query could get the end point.  You could then `UNION` these 2 queries and sort by `trace_number` to get gap starting positions on odd-numbered rows, and gap ending positions on even-numbered rows.

Comment: pretty common problem, google *sql gaps and islands*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your query has to do with the question, but you can identify gaps using `lag()`/`lead()`.  The idea is:

```
select (trace_number + 1) as start_gap,
       (next_tn - 1) as end_gap
from (select t.*,
             lead(trace_number) order by (trace_number) as next_tn
      from t
     ) t
where next_tn <> trace_number + 1;
```

This does not find them within a range.  It just finds all gaps.

Comment: I'd probably take this approach too

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this (adapt the where condition, put into clause "on") :

```
with Range (nb)   as (                                   
values 1000000                                                 
union all                                                
select nb+1 from Range                                   
where nb<=2000000                                        
)                                                        
select *                                                 
from range f1 left outer join trace f2       
on f2.trace_number=f1.nb                                  
and f2.trace_number between 1000000 and 2000000                  
where  f2.trace_number is null
```